# How would i pass data form database to broadcast reciever and recieve them again there?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alarms

I'm trying to develop birthday reminder application. I'm storing some data as name, last name, date of birthday.. I want to pass name variable to `BroadcastReciever` when user set the date of birthday, so when the alarm notify, I could display name of particular birthday. How could I do that? Here is small part of my code from activity where i'm sending data to `BroadcastReciever`:

```
if (dateSelected != null) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(AddBirthday.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("extra", getFirstName);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddBirthday.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Set the alarm for a particular time.
    //alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, test, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddBirthday.this, 1 , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, test, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

And here is `BroadcastReciever`:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private int MID;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Birthday Upcoming")
                .setContentText("Its " + "birthday" + "Dont Forget To Buy Some Present!").setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        notificationManager.notify(MID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
        MID++;
    }
}
```

I saw few questions about this, but I'm not sure how could I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver android:name="com.yourapplication.AlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.yourapplication.CUSTOM_INTENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When preparing your Intent to be fired off when the Alarm hits:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.yourapplication.CUSTOM_INTENT");
intent.putExtra("extra", getFirstName);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddBirthday.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, test, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

The name is stored in the Intent sent to `AlarmReceiver`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("extra");
    ...
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_icon)
        .setContentTitle("Birthday Upcoming for " + name)
        ...
```

Comment: I'm still getting null for the name. Maybe because i should get one more argument in getStringExtra?

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic Are you sure the `getFirstName` variable is not null?

Comment: Yes. I'm getting text there and sending to string after that.

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic This is a wild guess but could you try changing the flag for the `PendingIntent` to `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`